# Javascript respecting backslashes in input: negative lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex, split, backslash

In Javascript, I have a situation where I get input which I `.split(/[ \n\t]/g)` into an array. The point is that if a space is directly preceded by a backslash, I don't want the split to happen there.

E.g. `is_multiply___spaced_text` -> `['is','multiply','','','spaced','text']`

But: `is\_multiply\___spaced_text` -> `['is multiply ','','spaced','text']`

(Underscores used for spaces for clarity)

If this wasn't Javascript (which doesn't support lookbehinds in regex'es), I'd just use `/(?<!\\)[ \n\t]/g`. That doesn't work, so what would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: Do you also want to replace the backslashes from the output?

Comment: How do you mean exactly? Backslashes before other characters than spaces should remain in the output array if that's what you mean. BTW thanks for the edit indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the string, then use negative lookahead and then reverse the strings in the array:

```
var pre_results = "is\\ multiply\\   spaced text".split('').reverse().join('').split(/[ \t](?!\\)/);
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < pre_results.length; i++) {
    results.push(pre_results[i].split('').reverse().join(''));
}
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    document.write(results[i] + "<br>");
}
```

In this example, the result should be:

```
['text', 'spaced', '', 'is\\ multiply\\']
```

Comment: Nice solution! Only you need to filter out backslashes in the output and add an extra `results.reverse();` before the output (which you can just `console.log()` :P) to get the desired `['is multiply ','','spaced','text']`. Result: `var s,r,i;s="is\\ multiply\\   spac\\ed text";r=s.split("").reverse().join("").split(/[ \n\t](?!\\)/g);for(i=0;i<r.length;i++)r[i]=r[i].split("").reverse().join("").replace(/\\ /g," ");r.reverse();console.log(r);` (looks like rubbish lol)

Answer (score 0):

```
"is\_multiply\___spaced_text".replace(/\_/, " ").replace(/_/, " ").split("_");
```

Comment: I used underscores in my question to indicate spaces because SO wouldn't accept multiple spaces. Those underscores should be spaces and I can't be sure that the input won't contain any other underscores!